# Block any query in BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, query

I've been trying to block ANY queries in my BIND server with no success. 
I followed this post [Block ANY request in Bind](https://serverfault.com/questions/744613/block-any-request-in-bind) which says that I can use minimal-responses but it doesn't work.

None of the answers fit my current configuration.

```
view world {
    match-clients   { world-clients; };
    allow-recursion { none; };
    recursion       no;
    allow-transfer  { key XXXXXX; };

    minimal-responses yes;

    forwarders      { };

    include         "/etc/bind/world.conf";
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use iptables with `--hex-string` option for `any` type record.

This is DROP THE "ANY" REQUEST BASED ON COUNTER DEFIEND

```
-A  INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m string --hex-string "|0000ff0001|"  --algo bm --from 48 --to 65535  -m recent --set --name dnsanyquery  --rsource
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m string --hex-string "|0000ff0001|" --algo bm --from 48 --to 65535 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --name dnsanyquery --rsource -j DROP
```

Comment: Hi thanks, after some search I saw that the any query is no longer as a big security hole as before, they now use txt entry wich are bigger.

Comment: but its good option to have this deployed in your name server, since these kinds of attacks starts suddenly.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read [Andrew B.'s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/744614/451507)? He states that "there is no configuration option for dropping all queries of type `ANY`." The option `minimal-responses` helps in limiting attacks but you should start with response rate limiting as hspaans mentions in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/744619/451507).

The option `minimal-responses` will not block queries of type `ANY` but will limit the responses so as to make them less beneficial in amplification attacks.

Answer (score 1):

What is in "world.conf"? Is it possible that you are testing it from localhost or you private network? This would explain why it works for you even though you followed the guide correctly.

Comment: world.conf is a conf with all my zones (aprox 150). i tested it from different location. ^^