# Is it possible to block bind to answer to queries type "any"?

Tags: bind

I wanted to know if it was possible, like cloudflare is doing, to make bind deny any answer to queries from the type "any" like in `dig google.com any`

Comment: Maybe I m not sure but I m going to try soon then. Thanks for that because the title was not clear to me

Comment: You have other ideas in this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/744613/block-any-request-in-bind

Comment: If you can filter on the name requested and/or source IP, then you could use bind RPZ feature. But it does not allow to filter on the QTYPE. You can also look towards RRL to limit the trafic.